# Sequelize association create new row

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I wrote here yesterday, but I did not find the right solution,
I have such a connection (pictures 1)
How can I change my code so that I would create a `sizeChart`, bind `sizeChartParameters` to it, and `sizeChartAttributes` to it? I use sequelizeORM
Now there is a record only in `sizeChart`

```
const findChart = await models.sizeChart.create({
  categoryId:categoryId,
  nameChart:sizeChartName,
  include:[{
    required:true,
    model:models.sizeChartParameters,
    attributeValue:attributeValue,
    include:[{
      required:true,
      model:models.sizeChartAttributes,
      attributeName:attributeName,
    }]
  }]
});
```

sizeChart table

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {
  const SizeChart = sequelize.define('sizeChart', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    categoryId:{
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    nameChart:{
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  SizeChart.associate = function (models) {
    SizeChart.belongsTo(models['sizeChartParameters']);
  };
  return SizeChart;
};
```

sizeChartParameters table

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  const SizeChart = sequelize.define('sizeChartParameters', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    attributeValue: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  return SizeChart;
};
```

sizeChartAttributes table

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  const SizeChart = sequelize.define('sizeChartAttributes', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    attributeName: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  SizeChart.associate = function(models) {
    SizeChart.hasOne(models['sizeChartParameters'],{foreignKey:'attributeId'});
  };

  return SizeChart;
};
```

```
const findChart = await models.sizeChart.create({
  categoryId:categoryId,
  nameChart:sizeChartName,
  include:[{
    required:true,
    model:models.sizeChartParameters,
    attributeValue:attributeValue,
    include:[{
      required:true,
      model:models.sizeChartAttributes,
      attributeName:attributeName,
    }]
  }]
});
```